# SQL case statement when duplicate rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**Goal:** col: id needs to be unique, no duplicates

**Issue:** when `id_catelog1` is null, `id_catelog2` kicks in but makes multiple rows since some of them have multiple `id_catelog2`.

For the multiple ones, I need it to put "multiple" under `id_catelog_final` instead of `id_catelog2`.

This is my query so far:

```sql
select distinct
    id,
    name,
    id_catelog1,
    Large_id_catelog2,
    case 
        when id_catelog1 is null 
            then id_catelog2 
            else id_catelog1 
    end as id_catelog_final
from
    table
where 
    id is not null;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want aggregation with conditional logic:

```
select id, name,
       (case when max(coalesce(id_catelog1, Large_id_catelog2)) =
                  min(coalesce(id_catelog1, Large_id_catelog2))
             then min(coalesce(id_catelog1, Large_id_catelog2))
             else 'multiple'
         end)                  
from t
group by id, name
```

Comment: Hi, no luck. almost 90% of records getting dumped into 'multiple' when it should be like 5%

Comment: @msulol . . . I tried to do something fancy with `nullif()` and the logic wasn't correct.  It should work now.